# php mysql query with HAVING and MAX

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I need some help getting my mysql correct. 
I need to select one row which will have the maximum 'var' column value.
This is what I have right now but it doesn't give the maximum

```
SELECT a.* FROM `table` AS a GROUP BY a.var HAVING a.var = MAX(a.var) AND `code` = '1' AND `type` = '0';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ORDER BY` with `LIMIT 1`:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln
FROM `table`
WHERE `code` = '1' AND `type` = '0'
ORDER BY `var` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be all you need:

```
SELECT MAX(vari)
FROM TABLE
WHERE `code` = '1' AND `type` = '0'
```