# I need the category who has the most videos (max() didn't work)

Tags: mysql, max

I have a MySQL table with categories and video.

With `video_row['total_videos']` I get the total videos in each category. 'Till now I have no issues.

Because I am working on the CloudTags I need the category who has the most videos.
`max(video_row['total_videos']);` didn't work offcourse.

I use this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT *,  COUNT(v.id) AS total_videos
    FROM (".VIDEO_TABLE." v)
    LEFT JOIN (".CATEGORY_TABLE." c) ON (c.id = v.category_id)
    GROUP BY v.category_id";
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance,
Cruxy

Comment: The category who has the most videos, shouldn't result only one category? can you please show some sample data and the desired output.

Comment: Ok. What I want is something like: Category 1 (7 videos - cMax = 10)
Category 2 (8 videos - cMax = 10), Category 3 (2 videos - cMax = 10)

cMax is the most videos in one category

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought. Would this SQL query help you?

```
SELECT *, COUNT(v.id) AS total_videos
FROM video v
LEFT JOIN category c ON (c.id = v.category_id)
GROUP BY v.category_id
ORDER BY total_videos DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The query fetches only the row with the highest value of `total_videos`, which I understand is what you need.

Inspired by this: [php mysql query with HAVING and MAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156168/php-mysql-query-with-having-and-max)

EDIT: Nested SELECT statement would probably be a solution as well, but I would expect it to be slower.

Comment: Hi Pavel, I already done that and it works, but I prefer 1 query for the result I want (See above) instead of two.

Comment: I don't understand. I used one just one SQL query. Could you please describe the problem more elaborately?

Comment: Hi Pavel, I just used 2 queries (One is yours). I solved it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Good, I am glad. As I see you are new to StackOverflow, I kindly make a note it's possible to accept the answer, if it helped you, marking the tick symbol on the left side.